# "We cannot access the Google Analytics API. Please try again later"

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I recently downloaded the google analytics app on my iPhone 6s with the latest iOS. I have a google analytics account that I often view on my computer, but on my phone something is going wrong. I'm stuck on the login page, where I can see my account signed in, but when I select it I get the error message described in the title. It's been like this for about a day. I've had the google analytics account in use for about a month, and everything works fine on my computer. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, did you found some solution for this?

Comment: I recently upgraded from the firebase analytics interface to GA interface, and started getting this message from the GA app - I assume that it's something to do with permissions needing to be set in the GA account - not at all obvious...

Comment: Has this been resolved? Are you guys able to use the app? I am able to use it with an old account. I am not able to add new one.

Comment: Update. I allowed new account to access a project from an old account. I am not seeing this error anymore. I am still not able to see projects that I have on the new account.

Comment: Opened a support ticket with Firebase on this. Response I got was "... linking Firebase and Google Analytics puts Firebase data in an `App + Web property`, which are not supported in the Analytics app at this time. To view your data in the Google Analytics dashboards, please access from a desktop environment"

Comment: I still got this error! How to solve it?

Comment: Is this issue still not resolved? I hope google fixes this soon. It's almost mid 2020 already

Comment: It is June 2020 and still not fixed. Seems like they don't really care.